# Neural Networks API vs chipset NPU api

Tags: android

I want to try use NPU in Android smartpones and check the benefits and etc (project in university). But Im stacked on some questiong. We have `Android Neural Networks API`. But we also have a chipset NPU API like `Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine`. But there is any libraries or frameworks for Android devices, that will use a NPU regardless of a manufacturer of a chip (Samsung, Kirin, Snapdragon, etc), or I should write a code for every vendor?

Answer (score 1):

The NNAPI - The Android Neural Networks API (NNAPI) is an Android C API designed for running computationally intensive operations for machine learning on Android devices.

Typically these set of APIs are not directly invoked or used by apps running on android devices. NNAPI is meant to be called by machine learning libraries, frameworks, and tools that let developers train their models off-device and deploy them on Android devices.

Apps typically would not use NNAPI directly, but would instead use higher-level machine learning frameworks. Below is the Architecture diagram for Android Neural Networks API

[image]

As you can see from above Architecture - the NN APIs are called by ML frameworks or libraries and not by the apps running on android phones. Also you can see from this architecture that the Chip/Vendor based code reside below the NN API layer.

In Android ecosystem - ML Kit  is used by apps to get a handle to machine learning capabilities. I personally used ML mobile SDK for language detection using on-device ML. The ML Kit SDK uses Firebase-based APIs to for language identification and acts as "facade" and makes ML Features easily accessible from android apps